# Can't type in a Sweetalert2 input field

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

Using SweetAlert2 to display a confirmation window with an input textbox.   The dialog shows with the textbox but I can't type in it.

```
swal.fire({
                    title: "Cancel Appointments",
                    text: "Enter the reason for cancellation and click OK to cancel the selected appointments",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonText: "Cancel appointments",
                    confirmButtonColor: "red",
                    input: 'textarea',
                    inputPlaceholder: 'cancelation reason',
                    inputValidator: (value) => {
                        if (!(value)) {
                            return 'A reason is required';
                        }
                    }
                }).then((result) => {
                    if (result.isConfirmed) {
                        $("#cancelReason").val(result.value);
                        $("#deleteConfirmed").click();
                    } else {
                        $("#cancelReason").val('');
                    }
                });
```

I've looked at dozens of examples and my code matches.

I've also checked the element with DevTools and there's nothing out of the ordinary

```
<textarea class="swal2-textarea" placeholder="" style="display: flex;"></textarea>
```

I am using version 11.7.3.

Any ideas on where to start troubleshooting this one?

Comment: The problem seems to be if the button that triggers the popup is located inside a Bootstrap 5 Offcanvas.  If the button is on the page, the textarea works.